# Change color of element OnItemClick in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I'm working with ListViews and a GridView in my app. I've used a custom adapter for the GridView but not for the list.

[image]

As you can see, automatically it changes the background of the element when I click on it. But in the GridView is not happening the same. Have I got to do it manually? I would like some feedback for the user, the typical border or something like that. I upload the gridview screenshot too.

[image]

The GridView XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="100dp"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
```

And now the GridView Adapter's getView() part:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View layout=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    GridCrop gridElement;

    if (layout == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.crop_grid_element,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.cropImage);
        holder.text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
        layout.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) layout.getTag();
    }

    gridElement=list.get(position);
    holder.image.setImageResource(gridElement.getImage());
    holder.text.setText(gridElement.getTitle());
    return layout;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView text;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `grid.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);` on your GridView, your current selector is probably drawn under your non-transparent views from adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your **GridView XML.**

```
android:listSelector="#00343434"
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have to use a Selector directly in the background of the cell main layout:

**EXAMPLE :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/clr_main_green_pressed" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/clr_main_green_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/clr_main_green_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_selected="false"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read here in stackoverflow the listSelector attribute in XML... I tried it but didn't work... Until I tried with another color. So the answer is to add to GridView in xml:

android:listSelector="@color/Aqua" or whatever.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="100dp"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:listSelector="@color/Aqua"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
```